# Expo MediaLibrary getAlbumsAsync doesn't get WhatsApp Folders

Tags: expo, react-native

I'm building a photo organisation app where I want to take all the images / photos on the device and organise them into certain folders.

The biggest set of images lives in the "WhatApps Images" folder but when I happen to use the following code none of the WhatsApp folders appear.

```
const result = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync();
```

I'm guessing this is something to do with them not being user-defined albums (as mentioned in the docs) so I'm wondering what would be a way to access the assets residing in the WhatsApp Images folder?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the below code and make sure that you have the Whatsapp Images in your gallery.

Code:

```
MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync(false)
    .then(permissionRes => {
      if (permissionRes.granted) {
        MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync({ includeSmartAlbums: true })
        .then(res => {
          console.log('Successs : ', res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error : ', err.message);
        })
      } else {
        console.log('Something went wrong.')
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error : ', err.message);
    })
```

Above code working fine in my case